# Combining conditions in an IF condition

Tags: sql, t-sql, sql-server-2005

Can't we have this in a single SQL without using IF

```
IF (@PPRODUCT_TYPE_ID != '0')   
    SELECT * FROM PRODUCT 
    WHERE 
        PRODNAME = @pName 
    AND 
        PRODUCT_TYPE_ID IN (SELECT DISTINCT ID FROM PPRODUCT_TYPE)
ELSE
    SELECT * FROM PRODUCT 
    WHERE PRODNAME = @pName
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One method is:

```
SELECT p.*
FROM PRODUCT 
WHERE PRODNAME = @pName AND
      (@PPRODUCT_TYPE_ID <> '0' AND
       PRODUCT_TYPE_ID IN (SELECT NUMBER FROM DBO.MAKE_TABLE_USING_COMMASEPERATED_LIST(@PPRODUCT_TYPE_ID) )
      ) OR
      ( (@PPRODUCT_TYPE_ID = '0' OR @PPRODUCT_TYPE_ID IS NULL);
```

However, the original version might perform better, because two separate, simpler queries can be easier to optimize than one large query (particularly when the queries use parameters).

Comment: Your answer is perfect. One slight change I would suggest is using ISNULL(@PRODUCT_TYPE_ID,'0') = '0' in the second OR.

Comment: @DVT your method is correct, but it is not the most efficient use of a SARG statement and INDEXES

Comment: @BuddhiDananjaya Even in the case of "@PRODUCT_TYPE_ID" being a variable? I thought that we only need to be careful about that in the case of columns in query.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
SELECT * FROM PRODUCT 
WHERE 
    PRODNAME = @pName 
AND 
    (
    (PRODUCT_TYPE_ID IN (SELECT DISTINCT ID FROM PPRODUCT_TYPE) and @PPRODUCT_TYPE_ID != '0')
     OR
     (@PPRODUCT_TYPE_ID = '0')
     )
```